# collect data from dataverse table using list

Tags: canvas, powerapps, dataverse

I have a dataverse table with columns: EDS, country.

in the canvas app I have variable like this: allcurrentEDS = (1,2,3,4)

I want to search all current EDS in dataverse table and if they match get countres of that EDS-es.

I've tried `Filter(Sectors, EDS in allCurrentEDS, Sector)`

also tried lookup but have no result.

Comment: You can try implementing `ForAll`, and using `LookUp` inside it to look for `allcurrentEDS` individually.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work;

Lookup(Sectors, Filter(Sectors, EDS in allCurrentEDS))